# How to get atributes in <tr> tag when clicking an anchor inside a <td> that points to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I need some help.

I have a query to a sql database wich returns an array with all the data from the table.

Then I have a for to insert all array data to rows of a table.

This code block fills the table with the data from the array:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
 print ("
 <tr>
 <td>".$Users[$i][0]."</td>
 <td>".$Users[$i][1]."</td>
 <td>*****</td>
 <td><a href='javascript:Delete_User();'><img src='images/delete.png'/></a>/td>
 </tr>
 <tr>");
}
```

When we click in the anchor it points to the javascript function Delete_User();

The function Delete_User();

```
function Delete_User() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "delete_user.php" ,
    data: { id: "TABLE ROW ID HERE" },
    success : function() {
            window.location.href='utilizadores.php';
        }
        });
}
```

I was trying to solve this and if I add an atribute to the  tag maybe with jQuery or js I can get it.

My first attempt:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
 print ("
 <tr row-id='".$Users[$i][0]."'>
 <td>".$Users[$i][0]."</td>
 <td>".$Users[$i][1]."</td>
 <td>*****</td>
 <td><a href='javascript:Delete_User();'><img src='images/delete.png'/></a>/td>
 </tr>
 <tr>");
}
```

So, now How can I get that row-id value in the get parameter in the ajax function on the Delete_User js function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `$(this).parents('tr').attr('row-id')`

Comment: Okay, but where do I implement it? I'm kinda noob in jQuery and aJax.

Comment: Inside your `Delete_User` function..

Comment: Why don't you simply pass the user id to the Delete_User function?

Comment: I did this: <tr row-id='".$Users[$i][0]."'> and in the function I did this: data: { id: $(this).parents('tr').attr('row-id') }, but It's not working. The $_get stays nul

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest way:

```
 <td><a href='javascript:Delete_User(\"{$Users[$i][0]}\");'>
```

and

```
 function Delete_User( id ) {
```

Alternatively:

```
 <tr data-row-id='{$Users[$i][0]}'>
 ...
 <td><a href='javascript:Delete_User(this);'>
```

and

```
function Delete_User( el ) {
    var id = $(el).closest("tr").data( "row-id" );
    ...
```

Comment: I tryed this but it's not working. I might done it wrong. The anchor:
<a href='javascript:Delete_User(\"{$Users[$i][0]}\");'> The function:
    function Delete_User( rowid ) {
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "delete_user.php" ,
  data: { id: rowid) },
  success : function() {
    window.location.href='utilizadores.php';
   }
            });
    }

It's not working. But your solution seems very simple and that's what I'm looking foward too.

Answer (score 0):

add a class to your DOM element:

```
<a class='delete-button' ...></a>
```

and in your .js file add this:

```
$('a.delete-button').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    Delete_user($(this).closest('tr').attr('row-id'))
}
```

and add delcare your function

```
Delete_user(id){ ... }
```